# A bounded, continuous and monotone function must be uniformly continuous on an open interval

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

Consider $f : (a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ for $a, b \in \mathbb R$ where $f$ is monotone, continuous and bounded. Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Consider a set of $k$ evenly spaced points $p_i \in (a, b)$. Since $f$ is continuous on $(a, b)$ and $k$ is finite, $|f(p_i) - f(p_{i-1})| < \epsilon$ for all $i$ for $k$ large enough. Since $f$ is monotone, $|f(p_i) - f(p_{i-1})| \geq |f(x_1) - f(x_2)|$ for all $x_1, x_2 \in [p_{i-1}, p_i]$. Putting the previous two facts together, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[p_1, p_k]$.

To extend this to $(a, b)$ we use the fact that $f$ is bounded and so $f(a)$ is arbitrarily close to $f(p_1)$ and $f(b)$ is arbitrarily close to $f(p_k)$ for $k$ large enough.

**My question**

I am not sure that the only place I need the bounded hypothesis is in the last statement. I think continuity should be enough until the last statement. I think we don't need the bounded hypothesis if we instead consider $f$ over compact sets in $(a, b)$.

Comment: My approach would probably be to show that $f$ extends to a continuous function on $[a, b]$, which is compact.  The extension is $f(a)= \inf \{ f(x) \mid x \in (a, b) \} , f(b) = \sup \{ f(x) \mid x \in (a, b) \}$.  I think you need $f$ bounded to know that each of your intervals has "small" image for sufficiently large $k$.  Does that part of your proof hold for $f(x)= \frac 1x$ on $(0, 1)$?

Comment: $\frac 1 x$ on $(0,1)$ is continuous and monotone but not uniformly continuous.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy my point is that I only need the bounded hypothesis to go from any compact subset of this interval to the entire interval. In which case $1/x$ is uniformly continuous on any compact interval > 0